# ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, valueerror

I am trying to create a login system for a simple text-based game I am currently making. I used the PyCrypto module to encrypt and decrypt my data, yet it still seems to error whenever I pass a dict as a string and try to turn it into a dict:

```py
with open(f"users/{username}", "r") as encr_file:
      txt = encr_file.read()
      encr_file.close()
    
    info1 = encr.decrypt(txt)
    print(info1)
    info = dict(info1)
```

And here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    l.login()
  File "/home/runner/Space/files/login.py", line 93, in login
    info = dict(info1)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

And here is the dictionary that's causing it to error:

```py
{'username': 'rrxx', 'password': '123', 'money': 761, 'ship': 'Wheeler 11', 'guild': 'Military'}
```

*Note that this is just an example dict and I know that passwords should not be like this*

Can anyone help??

Comment: `dict` doesn't parse strings like `int` does if that's what you're expecting. If you want to parse a string as a dictionary, you'd want `ast.literal_eval`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: Or possibly `json.loads`, depending on use case; `ast.literal_eval` can do more, but is markedly slower, so if they can serialize and deserialize as JSON it can be faster (and more portable; you could read it with the JSON serializer available in your language of choice).

Comment: @Carcigenicate, thanks.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The flle he shows isn't in JSON format, it uses single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: @Barmar: Yar, the change would require that they serialize explicitly with `json.dumps`, not just stringify the `dict`.